# VueJS DOM is not accessible from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I have a simple VueJS app that looping the following DOM example:

```
<div v-for="site in topSites" class="col text-center topSites resBoo">...
```

So it generates repeated `divs` with the class `.topSites`.

Using vanilla JS, I could not access the generated DOM by VueJS. For example:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('.topSites').forEach(i => {i.style.background = 'blue'; console.log('aa',i)})
```

It does work, i.e the `querySelectorAll` method does not find the elements. However, running the above example from the browser's console, works fine.

I have tried to place the above code after declaring the Vue object. i.e:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {...}
})
```

Is there any way to access the DOM generated by Vue from outside Vue?

Comment: Usually problems like this are caused by trying to do something based on the DOM before the DOM actually exists. The fact that you're using VueJS won't make basic browser facilities not work generally, but if you try that *before* Vue has actually created those elements, then obviously it won't work.

Comment: I think you can use ```vue refs```. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/

Comment: @SajeebAhamed `refs` is to access the application's DOM from Vue itself, what I need is to access it from outside the Vue.

Comment: @Pointy How could and or access the Vue generated DOM from outside Vue, the `created` hook regarded in the answer below works, but it using Vue itself.

Comment: Well if you're using a framework like VueJS, you're stuck with the ways in which it works. Somehow your non-Vue code would have to figure out when the DOM has been built by the rest of the application, which to me seems like a fragile and error-prone approach compared to using the facilities provided by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your DOM custom operations in `mounted` or `updated` lifecycle hooks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.common.dev.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-for="site in topSites" class="col text-center topSites resBoo">{{site}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            topSites: ["site 1", "site 2"],
        },
        mounted: function () {
            const elems = document.body.querySelectorAll('.topSites');
            elems.forEach(i => {i.style.background = 'blue'; console.log('aa',i)});
        }
    })    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Or in `created` hook.

Comment: In mounted it returned empty NodeList, but created works! @Commander

Comment: In mounted it returns empty NodeList, hmm, strange. I have tested own example before it has been posted here.